# Mode function in Perl

Tags: perl

I need help with creating the mode function in Perl. I have written a code using help from different sources but every time the value differs. 
Mode - The maximum frequency of occurrence of an element in an array

Current Code -

```
@array = <STDIN>;
@sorted = sort { $a <=> $b } @array ;
for $i(@sorted)
{
    $cnt =0;
    for $j(@sorted)
    {
        if($i eq $j)
        {
            $cnt = $cnt + 1;
            $data{$i}= $cnt;
        }
    }
}
@modes = sort { $data{$a} <=> $data{$b} } keys %data;
$mode = $modes[-1];
```

Comment: Hi and welcome on StackOverflow. Could on please: 1. properly indent your code, 2. provide a sample input and output, 3. clearly point out what behavior you are getting compared to what you would like to get?

Comment: Input = (64630,11735 ,14216, 99233,14470 4978,73429,4978,38120,51135,67060,51135). Output = 4978. In case two numbers have same frequencies the smallest of them will be returned. Currently, when I take the input through <STDIN> the results are not correct. Request your inputs on the same

Comment: What does "The results are not correct" mean?

Comment: You specified "In case two numbers have same frequencies the smallest of them will be returned."  The end of your code does not do that.  If I remember correctly, when two values are equal, the `sort` routine will order them randomly.

Comment: @hymie that means that it returns the values from list randomly every time the code is executed.

Comment: The code you offerred above does not return values from the list randomly.  For example, it never returns the number 67060.  You should look at the key-value pairs in your `%data` hash and compare them to the numbers that your code returns.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having cleaned up your indentation and added `use strict` and `use warnings`, I get the following code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @array = <STDIN>;
my @sorted = sort { $a <=> $b } @array ;

my %data;

for my $i (@sorted) {
  my $cnt = 0;
  for my $j (@sorted) {
    if ($i eq $j) {
      $cnt = $cnt + 1;
      $data{$i}= $cnt;
    }
  }
}

my @modes = sort { $data{$a} <=> $data{$b} } keys %data;

say "The mode is: $modes[-1]";
```

And that seems to work correctly. So, perhaps, you need to explain the problem in a little more detail.

**Update:** Ok, so I think I now understand your problem - even though you really haven't said what it is very clearly.

If there are two potential values for the mode (i.e. two numbers that appear the same number of times) then you want the smallest one. And your current solution picks one of the potential values at random.

The problem is this line:

```
@modes = sort { $data{$a} <=> $data{$b} } keys %data;
```

This sorts the hash by the number of times the values appear. But if multiple values appear the same number of time, they can appear in any order - so you'll get a seemingly random number out of the end.

The solution is to add more intelligence to the sort so that in case of a tie, the smaller key sorts last. That would look like this:

```
my @modes = sort {
              $data{$a} <=> $data{$b}
              or
              $b        <=> $a
            } keys %data;
```

Comment: Dear All, Thanks for your help out here.  Input = (64630,11735 ,14216, 99233,14470 4978,73429,4978,38120,51135,67060,51135). Output = 4978. In case two numbers have same frequencies the smallest of them will be returned. Currently, when I take the input through <STDIN> the results are not correct. Request your inputs on the same.

Comment: @PankajSingh: "results are not correct" is a terrible bug report :-) What is incorrect about them?

Comment: @PankajSingh: I think I've worked out what you mean. Please see the update to my answer.